# Creating effects for a player?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class-hierarchy

I'll try to keep this short:

- I have a `PlayerEntity` class provided by the game engine, which has a `move_type` attribute
- `move_type` can be set to one at a time: `MoveTypes.NONE, MoveTypes.FLY, MoveTypes.WALK`
- I've subclassed the `PlayerEntity` class, and I want my subclass to be able to do stuff like `player.freeze(duration=5)`
- I'd also like to have custom effects like `player.burn(duration=3)`

Here's my first take at it:

```
class Player(game.PlayerEntity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._effects = []

    def add_effect(self, effect, duration=None):
        self.effects.append(effect)
        if duration is not None:
            delayed(duration, self.remove_effect, effect)
        self._apply_effects()

    def remove_effect(self, effect):
        if effect in self.effects:
            self.effects.remove(effect)
        self._apply_effects()

    def _apply_effects(self):
        if 'freeze' in self.effects:
            self.move_type = MoveTypes.NONE
        elif 'fly' in self.effects:
            self.move_type = MoveTypes.FLY
        else:
            self.move_type = MoveTypes.WALK
        if 'burn' in self.effects:
            self.ignite()
        else:
            self.extinguish()

    freeze = lambda self, duration: self.add_effect('freeze', duration)
    fly = lambda self, duration: self.add_effect('fly', duration)
    burn = lambda self, duration: self.add_effect('burn', duration)
```

However, I'd like to make it more flexible, for example have an `Effect` class.

Few questions I'm having problems with:

1. Would `Player` have `_effects` list and call `self._effects[0].apply(self, duration)`, or would `Effect` class have `player` attribute and just call it's own `apply(duration)`?
2. How would I interact with multiple effects? `Player` can only fly **or** be frozen, not both at once (due to `move_type`). However `burn` is completely independent effect.

Comment: Which game engine do you use/can you link to it? To me this seems more like a subjective question than a objective answerable one. For 2) one possibility could be to have multiple lists (movement [fly, frozen, slowed], attack [attackspeed_slowed, stunned]) and then defining priority on them or making them fifo/filo. So I guess it's more a game design question, or is there somewhere "defined" that burn is independent, but fly/frozen not (other than your "mind"/idea for the game).

Comment: @syntonym It's actually a Python wrapper for the C++ game engine: https://github.com/Source-Python-Dev-Team/Source.Python/ The reason burn is independent is due to the game engine; I can call `player.ignite()` whenever I want. However, freeze and fly are both done by setting the player's `movetype` attribute, so if the player is flying (`player.movetype == MoveTypes.FLY`) and I want to freeze him, I'll change `player.movetype = MoveTypes.NONE`, and he won't be flying anymore.

Comment: @syntonym You can find the `PlayerEntity` class from `addons/source-python/packages/source-python/players/entity.py`

Comment: What kind of flexibility would you like to have?

Comment: @syntonym I'd like the users to easily create their own effects, so like subclass my Effect class and override `activate()` and `deactivate()` methods, or something similae

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would have an `Effect` class, then store a list of `Effect` objects in the `Player` object. Call a method in `Player` to add `Effect` objects to this list. Go through the list of `Effect`s on each turn/tick to check stacks, update remaining durations, remove any with no remaining duration, and so on.
2. You can interact with multiple effects by creating custom `Effect` objects. For example, if you want a frozen state that allows movement and just increases the chance for that `Player` to receive a critical strike, create a new `Effect` that defines the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was looking for something similar to your #1, but haven't come up with a working solution yet. What comes to #2, can you read my comment on the original post? I meant that I should have different effects `freeze` and `fly`, but the game engine's `PlayerEntity` class restricts it so only one can be effective at once.

Comment: Can you add a new effect like `freeze_brittle` and have it call a method like `self.congeal()` in the same way that `burn` calls `self.ignite()`? Or are you limited to a rigid set of effects defined by the engine? Do `self.effects` and `self._effects` denote two different lists of effects, or is that a typo?

Comment: I'm limited to the engine's way of doing things. And `self.effects` was a typo :)

Comment: If you can't add to or change the effects included with the engine, it sounds like you're stuck with `freeze` impairing movement.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen of course you could alwayse "hack" effects into the game, e.g. setting the speed of the player to 0 every tick if he is effected by `myfreeze`.

Comment: @syntonym Yeah but my old solution already works, so I'm sure there must be an other way to create a similar effect with `Effect` classes

Answer (score 1):

The following code gives the possibility to define new effects with activate/deactivate and creates "categories". If two effects are in the same category the one with the higher priority will affect the player. Effects in different categories are independent.

There is a "flaw" in the implementation, imagine if the following happens:

- effect a is applied
- effect a is removed **not** because of timeout
- effect a is applied once more **before** the timeout of the first administration
- effect a is removed because the first administration duration was reached

This is probably easy fixed if `Effect` is turned into a class/metaclass.

Effect should really be a class/metaclass here, I just began to write it this way and wanted to finish it. Why metaclass? One way to solve the described problem would be to let `Effect` be a metaclass, so that `Freeze` is a class and one administration would be an instance of this class, with a delay that is coupled to this instance.

```
from collections import namedtuple, defaultdict

Effect = namedtuple("Effect", ["activate", "deactivate", "category", "priority", "name"])

class Player(game.PlayerEntity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Instead of list a priority list could/should be used
        self._effects = defaultdict(list)

    def add_effect(self, effect, duration=None):
        # Check if player allready suffers from effect
        if effect not in self._effects[effect.category]:

            # If the new effect has a higher priority than all others, activate it
            max_priority_effect = max(self._effects, key = lambda effect: effect.priority): 
            if effect.priority > max_priority_effect
                # Deactivate the old effect to savely change status
                max_priority_effect.deactivate(self)
                effect.activate(self)

            self._effects[effect.category].append(effect)

        if duration is not None:
            delayed(duration, remove_effect, effect)

    def remove_effect(self, effect):
        if effect.name in self._effects[effect.category]:
            priority_element = max(self._effects, key = lambda effect: effect.priority)

            # Might not be optimal?
            # If Effect is implemented as class do proper __eq__
            if effect.name == priority_element.name:
                # If the effect is the currently active effect deactive it and activate
                # the effect with the secondmost priority
                self._effects[effect.category][effect.name].deactivate()
                max(self._effects, key = lambda effect: effect.priority).activate()
                # If Effect is implemented as class do proper max() handling

            del self._effects[effect.category][effect.name]

#Effects:
freeze = Effect(
        activate   = lambda player: player.move_type = MoveTypes.None,
        deactivate = lambda player: player.move_type = MoveTypes.WALK,
        category   = "movement",
        priority   = 2,
        name       = "freeze")
fly = Effect(
        activate   = lambda player: player.move_type = MoveTypes.FLY,
        deactivate = lambda player: player.move_type = MoveTypes.WALK,
        category   = "movement",
        priority   = 1,
        name       = "fly")
burn = Effect(
        activate   = lambda player: player.ignite(),
        deactivate = lambda player: player.extinguish(),
        category   = "other",
        priority   = 0,
        name       = "burn")
```

EDIT:
Looks like I was wrong and metaclasses are not needed here. The following is an implementation with `Effect` being a class. Untested.

```
from collections import namedtuple, defaultdict
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Effect:

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.deactivate = self.if_fresh(deactivate)

    def if_fresh(self, f):
        if self.fresh:
            f()
            self.fresh = False

    def activate(self, player):
        # Overwrite me!
        pass

    def deactivate(self, player):
        # Overwrite me!
        pass

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return(self is other)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return(self.priority < other.priority)

class Burn(Effect):

    category = "other"
    priority = "0"

    def activate(self, player):
        player.ignite()

    def deactivate(self, player):
        player.extinguish()

[... other effects ... ]


class Player(game.PlayerEntity):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Instead of list a priority list could/should be used
        self._effects = defaultdict(list)

    def add_effect(self, effect, duration=None):
        # Check if player allready suffers from effect
        if effect not in self._effects[effect.category]:

            # If the new effect has a higher priority than all others, activate it
            max_priority_effect = max(self._effects[effect.category])
            if effect > max_priority_effect:
                # Deactivate the old effect to savely change status
                max_priority_effect.deactivate(self)
                effect.activate(self)

            self._effects[effect.category].append(effect)

        if duration is not None:
            delayed(duration, remove_effect, effect)

    def remove_effect(self, effect):
        if effect in self._effects[effect.category]:
            priority_element = max(self._effects)

            if effect is priority_element:
                # If the effect is the currently active effect deactive it and activate
                # the effect with the secondmost priority
                self._effects[effect.category][effect].deactivate()
                max(self._effects.activate())

            del self._effects[effect.category][effect]
```

Comment: It's not **exactly** what I was looking for, but it's still quite awesome. I'll accept a bit later on if I don't come up with something else! :) Just don't wanna rush with the accepting

Comment: Can you give details what you did exactly expect? Well, I guess it's not a class, but it should be easy to rewrite as one.

Comment: Don't know, the categories seem rather weird, probably because I haven't ever thought about them before. But I guess they work just fine and I can't come up with anything else either :)

Comment: That depends on how you want your effects to interact. I guess you could also do arbitrary interactions, but that would seem messy to me. Also effects can do check manually on the player._effects, so there is no real limitation. If later it becomes apparent that you need something else you can always refactor then.

Comment: Do you prefer some example code or is an explanation enough?

Comment: I think an explanation is enough, thanks :) No need for extra work :>